Order of points along a best fit line
I have a list of points (x,y) I need to be able to determine the order of points along a best fit (green) line.

AS shown in the picture I want them to be in the order 1,2,3 even though the x-coordinate is in the order x3,x1,x2 (I know the y-coordinate looks like the order I want but that is just this example)
If I have a line aX + bY + c=0, is there a way of finding a point normal to the line that passes through point(X1,Y1) ?
Looked at regression algorithms but they just seem to give me the line.
Looking at the picture I think I should be able to calculate each of the blue lines, that are normal to the green line and pass through the appropriate point.
Then solve for the points where the blue lines intersect the green line.
Then calculate the distance along the green line from a specific point of each of those green/blue intersections.
Is there a shortcut?
If I am only dealing with <100 points, should I just rotate them about the point on the green line where y=0 and use the new x-value as the sequence?

"finding a point normal to the line that passes through point(X1,Y1)" - this is an elementary question which is best asked (and answered) at Mathematics SE site, you just need to apply a couple of elementary geometry formulas. More importantly, you seem to have drawn the orthogonal regression, which is different from the regular linear regression. When applying the former, you should also be getting the projections for free, which in 2D will give you the desired ordering.

See some relevant links here.
If your points make an elongated cloud, you just do the PCA of your data (after centring the data first) and then take the first principal component.

I drew the picture as an orthogonal regression as that seemed like the way to go as it most closely resembled the problem I am trying to solve. I could not seem to find a library (.net) that did the heavy lifting. I don't really care if the best fit line generated with linear or orthogonal regression as I don't explicitly care about the magnitudes of the errors/residuals just the order of the orthogonal projection of the points along the best fit line

Is this a computer programming issue?

Yes. I need to keep a number of points that are unordered. I need to put them in sequence along a line. When adding/moving a point it needs a sequence attribute so the points can be accessed in order. The implementation language is c#.

Define some base point S at the line, and get it's direction vector D.
Then for every point P[i] calculate parameter of orthogonal projection onto the line using dot (scalar) product
t(i) = (P[i] - S).dot.D

and sort points by this parameter
Full expression for projection point coordinates is more complex, but I removed parts that don't influence on point order.
P.S. You can get base point S=(0, -C/B) and direction vector D=(-C/A, C/B) when A,B coefficients are non-zero

@Jamie_M_  Please notify if my answer is unclear.

That is super helpful. I think I understand it well enough to code it up. Thanks.
